# Mongo does not have a max() function, how do I work around this?

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection and need to find the max() value of a certain field across all docs.  This value is the timestamp and I need to find the latest doc by finding the largest timestamp.  Sorting it and getting the first one gets inefficient really fast.  Shall I just maintain a 'maxval' separately and update it whenever a doc arrives with a larger value for that field? Any better suggestions?
Thanks much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For sure if it will be big collection and if you need always display max timestamp you may need create separate collection and store statistic data there instead of order big collection each time.

```
statistic
{
  _id = 1, 
  id_from_time_stamp_collection = 'xxx',
  max_timestamp: value
}
```

And whenever new doc come just update statistic collection with id = 1(with $gt condition in query, so if new timestamp will be greater than max_timestamp then max_timestamp will be updated, otherwise - no).

Also probably you  can store and update other statistic data within statistic collection.

Comment: Andrew, yes the collections will get big very fast - imagine them to be log records (not exactly but same idea) - and they get into 10's of millions of rows in a day or so.  I don't have to display max_ts just use it to find the last saved record for a given key which has a series of records saved based on customer visits to site.  So something like what you've suggested is what I was thinking of.

Answer (score 20):

if you have an index on the timestsamp field, finding the highest value is efficientl something like

```
db.things.find().sort({ts:-1}).limit(1)
```

but if having an index is too much overhead storing the max in a separate collection might be good.

Comment: @dm Yes, I do have an index on the ts and that's exactly what I'm doing.  However this has to happen for each web hit on a relatively high traffic website so it has to have almost the same cost as a lookup by key. Else when the traffic spikes things go bad very fast.

Comment: I think this returns a cursor. You might be better off adding an index to the end: db.things.find().sort({ts:-1}).limit(1)[0]

Answer (score -3):

Try with db.collection.group

For example, with this collection:

```
> db.foo.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "a" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "a" : 200 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "a" : 230 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "a" : -2230 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "a" : 5230 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "a" : 530 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "a" : 1530 }
```

You can use `group` using

```
> db.foo.group({
    initial: { },
    reduce: function(doc, acc) {
        if(acc.hasOwnProperty('max')) {
            if(acc.max < doc.a)
                acc.max = doc.a;
        } else {
            acc.max = doc.a
        }
      }
    })
[ { "max" : 5230 } ]
```

Since there is no `key` value in `group` all the objects are grouped in a single result

Comment: This approach would be too slow. Other cons is that group doesn't work in sharded enviroment